# Import semicolon separated list into a new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which requires refactoring to support new functionality, the table is in the following format:

```
RefID (int), Data (nvarchar(255))
--------------
1, 161;162;163;164
2, 131;132;133;144
```

I need to transform this data and import it into a new table as follows:

```
ID (PK), RefID (int), Data (int))
-------------------------------------------
1,1,161
2,1,162
3,1,163
4,1,164
5,2,131
6,2,132
:   :
```

etc.

Basically, split the semicolon delimited list (data) and create a new record for each one, converting to INTs along the way.

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server? And did you try anything?

Comment: Hi Juergen, its SQL server.

Comment: http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/best-split-function-tsql-delimited

Answer (score 3):

You can use a table valued function that split the string and use it to populate your table. Here is one Split function (credit to @AaronBertrand for the code):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
```

Then you just need to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ResultTable(RefID, Data)
SELECT  A.RefID,
        B.[Value]
FROM dbo.YourTable A
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[SplitString](A.Data,';') B
```

[**Here is an sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/774d6/2) with a demo of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can write sql script to handle this... but if this is a one time deal and don't mind using other means...

```
select replace(convert(varchar(100),RefID) + ';' + Data,';',',') Data
from table
```

Then save the result to a csv and import. Pretty quick solution. Or you can write a script. ;)

Comment: Thanks Sam, but this is going to form part of a much larger refactoring script which will be run against an existing database, so it will need to be a script or stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto @Lamak's answer... here is the pivot part

```
SELECT Id, [1],[2],[3],[4]
FROM (
    SELECT a.Id, b.value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Id ORDER BY a.Id) ColNumber
    FROM dbo.YourTable a
    CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(DATA,',') b) pvt
PIVOT (MIN(value) FOR ColNumber IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])) p
```